# Extension of a linear map from a one dimensional subspace to its closure

Tags: functional-analysis, banach-spaces

Let $F$ be a linear subspace of a normed space $E$. Let $G$ be a Banach Space. Prove that

1. For any continuous linear map $T:F\rightarrow G$, there exists exactly one continuous map $\overline{T}:\overline{F}\rightarrow G$ such that $\overline{T}\mid_{F}=T$.
2. The map $\overline{T}$ is linear.
3. $||\overline{T}||=||T||$

Comment: This is pretty easy. What went wrong with your attempts?

Comment: The title seems to conflict with the question - an arbitrary subspace of a Banach space is very different from a one dimensional subspace.

Comment: For any $x \in \overline{F}$, there is $(x_n) \subset F$ such that $x_n \to x$. Define $\overline{T}x = \lim \limits_{n \to \infty} x_n$. 

Show that $\overline{T}$ is well-defined, linear , etc . . .

Comment: I have problem with the last part. Any hint ?